# Cytoscape.js cy.style().fromJson() add instead of replace?

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

I want to separate the style from color schemes in a Cytoscape.js 3.1 graph. According to http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.style, I initialize and then add to `cy.style()`:

```
var mystyle = [
    {
        "selector": "node",
        "css":
        {
            "border-opacity": 1.0,
            'label': function(ele)
            {
              if(ele.data('Labels_EN')) {return ele.data('Labels_EN')[0];}
              ...
         }, ...
    ];

var bright = [
    {
        "selector": "node",
        "css":
        {"background-color": "white";}
    }];

cy = cytoscape(
    {
        container: mycontainer,
        style: mystyle
    });

cy.style().fromJson(bright).update();
```

Unfortunately, the call to `cy.style().fromJson()` seems to automatically invoke `cy.style().resetToDefault()`, as it removes the existing style.
How can I prevent Cytoscape.js from deleting my existing style and instead add to it using JSON? I need this functionality so that I don't have to put the complete style information in all my color scheme files, which makes it harder to maintain.

P.S.: As a workaround, I merged two style files like this:

```
function mergeJsonArraysByKey(a1,a2)
{
    let map1 = new Map();
    let map2 = new Map();
    for(i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {if(a1[i].selector) {map1.set(a1[i].selector,a1[i]);}}
    for(i=0;i<a2.length;i++) {if(a2[i].selector) {map2.set(a2[i].selector,a2[i]);}}
    let merged = [];
    map1.forEach((value,key,map) =>
    {
        if(map2.has(key))
        {
            merged.push($.extend(true,{},value,map2.get(key)));
        } else
        {
            merged.push(value);
        }
    });
    map2.forEach((value,key,map) =>
    {
        if(!map1.has(key))
        {
            merged.push(value);
        }
    });
    return merged;
}

function initGraph(container, graph)
{
    let merged = mergeJsonArraysByKey(mystyle,bright);
    cy = cytoscape(
    {
        container: container,
        style: merged
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the json rather than appending to the stylesheet.  You can do whatever you want with the json, whereas `cy.style()` can be modified in only particular ways to prevent issues.

`cy.style().fromJson( sheetA.concat( sheetB ) )`

Comment: The answer is amended